# How to search different digits in numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which `split` the `input` `value` on `space` and I looped through to search them in a number but only the last value is shown (checked) not the other before it .

One solution can be by removing `else` that way it worked fine but this way when changing the value the `checked` number remain intact(last searched result are also shown).

```js
let SearchingNumbers_btn = document.getElementById('SearchingNumbers_btn');
SearchingNumbers_btn.addEventListener("click", refree);

function refree() {
  var reader = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox_inputs")
  for (let i = 0; i < reader.length; i++) {
    var readerText = reader[i].value
    var readerText1 = readerText.trim()
    var reed = document.getElementById("allNumbers").value;
    var reed1 = reed.trim()
    var myDiffValues = reed1.split(" ");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myDiffValues
    if (reed != '') {
      for (var item of myDiffValues) {
        if (readerText1.indexOf(item) > -1) {
          reader[i].checked = true;
        } else {
          reader[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      reader[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="allNumbers" />
<button id="SearchingNumbers_btn">Select all</button>

<br><br>
<br>

<input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="2528" data-u-mobile="2528" />
<span>2528</span>

<input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="2529" data-u-mobile="2529" />
<span>2529</span>

<input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="2527" data-u-mobile="2527" />
<span>2527</span>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

> One strange behavior it is showing is when lot of space is entered in the input all checkboxes get checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it much more easily :)

### Explanation

1. First of all you read your inputs (`checkbox_inputs`).
2. Then you
   read just once the numbers (`allNumbers`) and you can trim and split
   in one line.
3. Last step: for each one of your checkboxes you set the `checked` value if the `allNumbers` list includes the expected value. `false` otherwise.

### Working Example

```js
let SearchingNumbers_btn = document.getElementById('SearchingNumbers_btn');
SearchingNumbers_btn.addEventListener("click", refree);

function refree() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox_inputs");
  var allNumbers = document.getElementById("allNumbers").value.trim().split(" ");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = allNumbers
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].checked = allNumbers.includes(inputs[i].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="allNumbers" />
<button id="SearchingNumbers_btn">Select all</button>

<br><br>
<br>

<input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="2528" data-u-mobile="2528" />
<span>2528</span>

<input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="2529" data-u-mobile="2529" />
<span>2529</span>

<input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="2527" data-u-mobile="2527" />
<span>2527</span>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks nicely done(+1) . But as it is most of the time I get stuck in the `for` loop matching   only last value . Can there are other ways around it to match all values not only last one

Comment: In your solution you cycle through all numbers and set true or false each time, overriding the previous value. This obviously means the last one is selected. You should stop looping once a `true` value is read, for example with the keyword `continue` if the value is already true. But honestly I think it just makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Yes that's always the case , can there are other ways to select all using `for` loop

Comment: You can put inside the nester for `if (inputs[i].checked) { continue; } else {inputs[i].checked = allNumbers[j] == inputs[i].value; }` but I would not recommend it. `includes` just makes it work fine with one line.

Comment: What if one of the digits matches than also the input is checked , how to do that . Can you tell about in my question that when lot of spaces entered than also the checkbox are `checked